# javascript/html: привязываться к id, class/element или data-атрибутам?

Tags: javascript, html, ооп, code-style, behaviors

Каким образом удобнее обращаться к элементам HTML из JavaScript? Какие в настоящий момент существуют хорошие практики для этого? Хотелось бы, чтобы привязка следовала конкретной несложной логике и имела структуру, была по стилю похожа на ООП.

Возьмем простую задачу - на странице нужно найти кнопку добавления товара в корзину и привязать к ней обработчик. При нажатии кнопки нужно также получить информацию о товаре из HTML - id товара, некоторые его характеристики (название, цвет, размер - для отображения окна "вы добавили в корзину то-то").

Я вижу несколько вариантов (на примере кнопки добавления товара в корзину):

- Использовать id `$('#item-add-to-cart-button')`, характеристики также ищем по id. Не очень удобно, так как для каждого элемента приходится придумывать (или генерировать) уникальный ID, особенно если на странице несколько однотипных элементов (`$('#item-add-to-cart-button-1278')`?). ID - это как глобальные переменные, мне кажется, что использовать их - не очень хороший тон.
- Использовать структуру html и class'ы `$('.item button.add-to-cart')`, характеристики получаем так же или через `parent/closest/find` - ближе к желаемому, позволяет привязаться к нескольким однотипным элементам, похоже на ООП (можно использовать логику item->button->add-to-cart). Однако мы зависим от структуры html, и если дизайнер/верстальщик поменяет что-то в css/html (заменит `button` на `a` или `.add-to-cart` на `.add-to-cart-big`), привязка перестанет работать.
- По data-атрибутам. Здесь большой простор для экспериментов, так как можно привязываться и к имени атрибута, и его значению, можно задавать несколько атрибутов элементу, его родителям, потомкам. Но как построить удобную структуру для обращения к элементам через data-*? Например, можно так `$(('[data-type="item"] [data-type='add-to-cart-button]'))` (элемент с `data-type=add-to-cart-button` внутри элемента с `data-type=item`) или просто  `$([data-js="item-add-to-cart-button"])`. Плюс в том, что верстальщик уже, скорее всего, будет внимательнее относиться к таким атрибутам, второй плюс в неограниченной гибкости, но это порождает сложности - нужно придумывать пространства имен для названий/значений data-атрибутов, которые будут использоваться при поиске элементов через JS.

Хотелось бы понять, какой на текущий момент накоплен опыт разработчиков по  внедрению на страницу поведения на javascript с минимальной зависимостью от структуры HTML и стилей CSS (чтобы дизайнер/верстальщик и js-программист не мешали друг другу). Есть ли какие-то методологии/паттерны?

Я искал в гугле ответ на этот вопрос, но в основном рассматривается скорость доступа по id/class/data-*, а меня интересует здесь не скорость, а удобство (командной) разработки и хорошая организация кода.

Нашел несколько статей на тему атрибутов data:

- http://roytomeij.com/blog/2012/dont-use-class-names-to-find-HTML-elements-with-JS.html
- https://toddmotto.com/data-js-selectors-enhancing-html5-development-by-separating-css-from-javascript/
- https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/

Но они довольно старые, думаю, что со времени их опубликования было накоплено много практического опыта. Прошу участников сообщества им поделиться!

Comment: https://ru.bem.info/methodology/ - это юзает яндекс и гугл

Comment: @iXplo спасибо за ссылку! Вы могли бы написать поподробнее? Каким образом это можно использовать, например, для примера с корзиной в вопросе?

Comment: @iXplo кстати, в каком проекте google использует БЭМ?

Comment: Будет примерно так: `$('.selling-item__add-to-cart-button')`. Следующее довольно бессмысленно при использовании этой методологии: `$('.selling-item .selling-item__add-to-cart-button')`

Comment: http://yandex.ru

Comment: для корзины вообще кроме id корзины не нужно никуда лезть в html, все должно браться из данных, а не из разметки Да и id Не нужен в принципе

Comment: пример недоступной кнопки по БЭМ: `<button class="selling-item__add-to-cart-button selling-item__add-to-cart-button_out-of-order">+</button>` это всё ужасно длинно, но никаких драк между верстальщиками и js-кодерами возникнуть не должно. Я это не использую, тк команда обычно небольшая. И проекты не глобальные.

Comment: google bem: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite

Comment: а лично меня оч устраивает обычный каскадный подход на смеси id, классов и атрибутов. быстро и читаемо. если прям хочется отделить - пускай js-кодеры работают с `data-` аттрибутами. через jQuery вообще удобно

Comment: @Grundy что значит "браться из данных"? Вы имеете в виду "сервер должен возвращать эти данные в ответ на post по добавлению товара в корзину"? Возможно. Я имел в виду, что для формирования самого запроса может потребоваться несколько параметров со страницы - количество, id размера, выбранного покупателем (в добавление к id модели) и т. д. А также отображать всплывающее окно "Вы действительно хотите добавить ЭТО в корзину (цвет, размер, название)" можно и без обращения к серверу. В целом, корзина - это просто пример.

Comment: Недоступная кнопка должна делаться через disabled! Всех, кто использует классы вместо встроенной функциональности, надо больно бить.

Comment: @PavelMayorov полностью согласен. Я описал конкретную модификацию кнопки, тк недоступна она может по нескольким причинам. Пофикшу свой камент. Уже нельзя :( В общем вот: `<button class="selling-item__add-to-cart-button selling-item__add-to-cart-button_out-of-order" disabled>+</button>`